# I have a 23.6 monitor native 1920x1080 will it support 2560x1080

Tags: display

My monitor is the Asus ve247h native resolution is 1920x1080 my my new graphics card supports 2560x1600 will it support 2560x1080?

Comment: Are you asking about the graphic card or about the monitor?

Comment: for LCD-type screens, native resolution == maximum resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Your monitor supports a maximum resolution of 1920x1080, your new graphics supports a maximum resolution of 2560x1600... The new graphics card should detect the monitors maximum capabilities and only display in a maximum of 1920x1080, in Windows you will likely not even be able to select a higher resolution, doing so will cause the monitor to not display an image and could possibly damage the monitor.

With your current monitor, the highest resolution it can display is 1920x1080, so to answer your question directly: No, it will not support 2560x1600 regardless of the graphics card.